# What is the restriction of a complex vector space $V_C$ to be a real vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> Let V be a finite-dimensional complex vector space, and $T\in L(V)$. Let $W=Res_{\mathbb C/\mathbb R}V$ be the Restriction of $V$.  Let S=$Res_{\mathbb C/\mathbb R}T\in L(W)$ be the induced operator on W. Suppose that $T$ has $\lambda$ as a non-real eigenvalue. Prove that $S_C$ has both $\lambda$ and $\overline \lambda$ as eigenvalues

The above is the problem I was trying to solve, but I don't understand the meaning of "restriction of V".

I know that complex vector space can be regarded as the "complexification" of a real vector space.
For example, suppose $V$ is a real vector space over the real number field $\mathbb R$, and $ V \times V=V_{ C}$ can be regarded as the "complexification" of $V$, so $V_C$ is regarded as a complex vector space on a field $\mathbb C$.

Then as so far, my understanding of this "restriction" of a complex vector space $V_C$ over $\mathbb C$ means that $V_C$ is "degrade" back to $V$ and make $V$ to be a real vector space over $\mathbb R$. And then in $V_C$, all vectors are in the form of $u+iv$ and can be scaled by complex numbers such as $a+bi$, but after the restriction, the vectors in $V$ are just $u,v$ and so on and can only be scaled by real numbers. Is this right?

Comment: Abstractly, $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, meaning that there is an action $\mathbb{C} \times V \to V$ of scalar multiplication: the restriction $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the restriction of this action to $\mathbb{R} \times V \to V$: we simply "forget" how to multiply by any complex number which is not real. If $v \in V$, then $v$ and $iv$ are proportional since they are a complex multiple of each other, but in $V_\mathbb{R}$ the vectors $v$ and $iv$ are linearly independent, since we only allow real-linear combinations.

Comment: @Joppy So you mean that suppose $V$ is complex vector space, and the restriction of $V$ is a new vector space $V'$ it still contains vectors like $u+iv$, $u$, and, $iv$, but on this new vector space $V'$ we only allow the real scaling. That is we can't have something like $(a+bi)(u+iv)$, but we do have $\lambda(u+iv)$ for $\lambda$ being real number. Or just $u+iv$ shouldn't appear in $V'$ since now $V'$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your quandry... but, first, if $V'$ is a complex vector space obtained by complexifying a real vector space $V$, it is *not* the case that the "restriction of scalars" of $V'$ is $V$ again. It is isomorphic to a direct sum of two copies. The operations of "complexification" and "restriction of scalars from complex to real" are not *inverse*, but "adjoint", in a categorical sense.

It is structurally better (though not more explanatory at a first pass) to say that the complexification of a real vector space $V$ is $V\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$, rather than more ad-hoc, coordinate-dependent descriptions.

In particular, to be clear, if we repeatedly complexify-restrict-complexify-restrict we'll double the real dimension in each cycle of complexify-restrict.

Comment: You mean that the restriction of a complex vector space $V'$ won't give back the real vector space $V$ whose complexification is $V'$. Thus, can I say that if I make a restriction of scalar on the complex vector space $V'$, then the result $ResV'$ is a so-called real vector space with all the same vectors in $V'$, but the scalars are from $\mathbb R$? That is, in $ResV'$ there can be vectors like $(u+iv)$, but I can only scale it by real numbers. Is this a right understanding?

Comment: Yes, it will _not_ give back that original real vector space. Yes, the restriction of $V'$ is the same _set_, but we only allow scalar multiplication by real numbers, not complex. Yes, this is an odd thing to do, but it does have some uses. :)